# Java question about ArrayList<Integer>[] x

Tags: java, arrays, generics, arraylist

I have always had this one issue with arrays of ArrayLists. Maybe you can help.

```
//declare in class
private ArrayList<Integer>[] x;

//in constructor
x=new ArrayList[n];
```

This generates a warning about unchecked conversion.

But

```
x=new ArrayList<Integer>[n];
```

is a compiler error.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: There's a whole bunch of questions and answers on SO about generics and arrays.

Comment: why not try List<List<Integer>>?

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer your question, but you're trying to use an array of ArrayLists, so you are probably better suited to using a LinkedList of Integer arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't make a array of generics lists. Fortunately, there are workarounds. And even more fortunately, there is a nice site about [Generics](http://www.angelikalanger.com/Articles/Papers/JavaGenerics/ArraysInJavaGenerics.htm) with more information than you'd ever want to know. The link goes straight to the Arrays in Java Generics part.

Answer (score 5):

I think you cannot make array of generic arraylist because no generic information will be available at runtime.Instead you can do like this:

```
List<Integer>[] arr=new ArrayList[30];
arr[0]=new ArrayList<Integer>();//create new arraylist for every index.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<?>[] x;
x=(ArrayList<? extends Integer>[]) new ArrayList<?>[10];
x[0] = new ArrayList(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the flowing code:

```
public class Test {
    ArrayList<Long>[] f0;
    ArrayList<Long> f1;
    ArrayList[] f2;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        Field[] fs = t.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for(Field f: fs ){
            System.out.println(f.getType().getName());
        }

    }

}
```

You will get:

```
[Ljava.util.ArrayList;
java.util.ArrayList
[Ljava.util.ArrayList;
```

Because Java don't support generic array. When you declare：

```
private ArrayList<Integer>[] x;
```

The compiler will think it is :

```
private ArrayList[] x;
```

So, you should do like that:

```
int n = 10;
ArrayList<Long>[] f = new ArrayList[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    f[i] = new ArrayList<Long>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't have been an error. A warning is enough. If nobody can create an `ArrayList<Integer>[]`, there is really no point to allow the type.

Since javac doesn't do us the favor, we can create the array ourselves:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
<E> E[] newArray(Class<?> classE, int length)
{
    return (E[])java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(classE, length);
}

void test()
    ArrayList<Integer>[] x;
    x = newArray(ArrayList.class, 10);
```

The type constraint isn't perfect, caller should make sure the exact class is passed in. The good news is if a wrong class is passed in, a runtime error occurs immediately when assigning the result to `x`, so it's fail fast.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems you want to avoid the warning about Generics when you simply write

`ArrayList[] x=new ArrayList[n];`

as well as remove the compilation error, of `x=new ArrayList<Integer>[n];`

You can use the generic type `<?>` to satisfy both the conditions, something like:

```
ArrayList<?> x[]=new ArrayList[n];
```

You might want to refer to the link below for knowing more about generics: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html